# "p" cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, class, variables

I have to use a switch statement to allow a user to select what they want to do, if they select "1", it will allow them to add a person to a database. In the switch statement for "1", i am getting a syntax error stating that "p" cannot be resolved to a variable. However, I have tried everything i can possibly think of to get this to work and it will not. any idea?

```
package hartman;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Printer.printWelcome();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean keepRunning = true;
    while (keepRunning) {
        Printer.printMenu();
        Printer.printPrompt("Please enter your operation: ");

        String userSelection = keyboard.nextLine();

        switch (userSelection) {
        case "1":
            Database.addPerson(p);
            break;
        case "2":
            Database.printDatabase(personList);
            break;
        case "3":
            Printer.printSearchPersonTitle();
            String searchFor = keyboard.nextLine();
            Database.findPerson(searchFor);
            break;
        case "4":
            keepRunning = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    Printer.printGoodBye();
    keyboard.close();
}

 }
```

This is Database.java -

```
package hartman;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Database {
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
private static ArrayList<Person> personList;

public Database() {

}

public static void addPerson(Person personList2) {
    Printer.printAddPersonTitle();
    Printer.printPrompt("  Enter first name: ");
    String addFirstName = keyboard.nextLine();

    Printer.printPrompt("  Enter last Name: ");
    String addLastName = keyboard.nextLine();

    Printer.printPrompt("  Enter social Security Number: ");
    String addSocial = keyboard.nextLine();

    Printer.printPrompt("  Enter year of birth: ");
    int addYearBorn = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());

    System.out.printf("\n%s, %s saved!\n", addFirstName, addLastName);

    Person person = new Person();
    person.setFirstName(addFirstName);
    person.setLastName(addLastName);
    person.setSocialSecurityNumber(addSocial);
    person.setYearBorn(addYearBorn);
    personList.add(personList2);
}

    public static void printDatabase(ArrayList<Person> personList) {
    System.out
            .printf("\nLast Name           First Name           Social Security Number  Age\n");
    System.out
            .printf("=================== ===================  ======================  ===\n");
    for (Person p : personList) {

        System.out.printf("%-20s%-21s%-24s%s\n", p.getLastName(),
                p.getLastName(), p.getSocialSecurityNumber(),          p.getAge());

    }

}

public static ArrayList<Person> findPerson(String searchFor) {
    ArrayList<Person> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Person p : personList) {
        boolean isAMatch = false;

        if (p.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;

        }
        if (p.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;

        }
        if (p.getSocialSecurityNumber().contains(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;
            ;
        }
        if (String.format("%d", p.getAge()).equals(searchFor))
            if (isAMatch) {

            }
        matches.add(p);
    }
    return matches;

}

}
```

Comment: `Database.addPerson(p);` - what is `p`?

Comment: You have not declared the variable `p`, which would cause this line to fail.

`Database.addPerson(p);`

Comment: Exactly, there is no `p` defined

Comment: Does "everything you can possibly think of" include actually having a variable called `p`?

Comment: how do i fix this? I have no idea where to place it because it freaks out if i try to anywhere.

Comment: Well, what do you want `p` to be?

Comment: Maybe you want something like `Database.add(new Person())`?

Comment: p has to be the data i typed in to save to the array

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cant resolve p to a variable, because you declare p nowhere.

### Better solution:

I think its much nicer to do the person creation process directly in the database, so do the following:
Change Database.java to this:

```
public static void addPerson() {
Printer.printAddPersonTitle();
Printer.printPrompt("  Enter first name: ");
String addFirstName = keyboard.nextLine();

Printer.printPrompt("  Enter last Name: ");
String addLastName = keyboard.nextLine();

Printer.printPrompt("  Enter social Security Number: ");
String addSocial = keyboard.nextLine();

Printer.printPrompt("  Enter year of birth: ");
int addYearBorn = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());

System.out.printf("\n%s, %s saved!\n", addFirstName, addLastName);

Person person = new Person();
person.setFirstName(addFirstName);
person.setLastName(addLastName);
person.setSocialSecurityNumber(addSocial);
person.setYearBorn(addYearBorn);
personList.add(person);
}
```

Change first code to:

```
Database.addPerson();
```

Comment: corrected the code, sorry its to late in the night -.-!

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at hartman.Database.addPerson(Database.java:36)
 at hartman.Main.main(Main.java:24)

Comment: @user3562527 which line is 36?

Comment: Getting this now: Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at hartman.Database.addPerson(Database.java:35)
 at hartman.Main.main(Main.java:24)

Comment: you have to tell us which line is which in your code!

Comment: @user3562527 What code is on the line referenced in the exception (Currently Database.java:35)?

Comment: it's these: 
  personList.add(person);

Database.addPerson();

Comment: change `private static ArrayList<Person> personList;` to
 `private static ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();`

Comment: Add `personList = new ArrayList<Person>();` to the constructor of `Database`.  Remove `static` from all of `Database`'s methods.  Initialise a new `Database` inside your `main` method and assign it to a local variable.  Use that local variable in place of the word `Database` in all of the calls within `main`.

Comment: has to be all in the database.java. Its a midterm project and thats the requirement.

Comment: @user3562527 did you try my correction!?
DavidWallace solution is much better but mine should work as a quick dirty fix

Comment: yes robert, it wont work because Database.addPerson(); is null. 

yes, i understand ive been staring at this for 8 hours now.

Comment: No, your problem is that `Database.personList` is null, and that's why Robert told you to initialise it.

Comment: _i mean this one:_
change in `Database.java` the following code `private static ArrayList<Person> personList;` to  `private static ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();`

Comment: it doesnt store data now

Comment: oh god i fixed it, i dont know how though lmao